In cloud (say AWS), what is the difference b/w golden image and hardened image of OS?
I have tried to search a lot but all I get is their definitions which more or less sound similar.

I would like to know if they are same?
If not, what are specific differences?


You have two good answers to your question. You have posted the same follow-up comment to each answer. Can you [edit] your question to clarify your understanding of each term, including references to where you got the definitions, and where exactly your confusion lies with the two definitions? Otherwise, the answers you already have are about as good as you can get with a question containing this little information.

Please don't cross-post.

This is very context dependent, but at a high-level:

A golden OS image is designed for general purpose use, and likely has a bunch of general purpose tools installed. It's (hopefully!) kept up to date with security advisories but isn't overly restrictive.
A hardended image has the security turned up to the max (again, where "to the max" may dependent on your use case). Anything non-essential which might increase the attack surface is removed, and anything essential is configured to be in "default reject" mode, with the possible exception of one and only one management interface.

Note there's nothing "cloud" specific about this, exactly the same concepts have applied ever since we were rolling out OS images onto physical bits of tin in a data centre, or onto a hypervisor sitting in our server cupboard.

So I assume hardened image is golden but reverse may/ not be true. One question - Can hardened image be modified to install additional required software and rebuilt?

That's more a business process question than a technical one. A hardened image is often made for security or other compliance reasons, so what you should do with it is a question for your specific circumstances.

"Golden image" is derived from the older "golden master" for mass duplication - that is, the thing which all the duplicates are made from.
"Hardened" in this context relates to security.
It is therefore possible that a golden image may or may not be also hardened.

So I assume hardened image is golden but reverse may/ not be true. One question - Can hardened image be modified to install additional required software and rebuilt?

Sure .. subject to checking that it's not defeated the hardening, and having some book keeping as to which of your images are "hardened"
